# SQL SUM Group By with Case statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I'd like to group by state and sum up the total pledge amount, but if the pledge status is equal to canceled sum up the total paid. I'm not sure the best way to do this?

Thank you for feedback and help!

```
SELECT        
dbo.FoundationCompanies.companyState, 

CASE WHEN dbo.FondationOrder.pledgeStatus = 'canceled' THEN
 (
 SELECT        SUM(paid) AS total
 FROM            dbo.FoundationInvoice
 WHERE        (orderId = dbo.FondationOrder.orderId)
 ) 
 ELSE 
 dbo.FondationOrder.pledgeAmount 
 END AS pledgeAmount

 FROM            
 dbo.FoundationCompanies

 INNER JOIN
 dbo.FondationOrder 

 ON 
 dbo.FoundationCompanies.compId = dbo.FondationOrder.compId

 GROUP BY dbo.FoundationCompanies.companyState
 ORDER BY dbo.FoundationCompanies.companyState
```

**Example data:**

Algonquin   2500.00

Atlanta 500000.00

Batesville  10000.00

Batesville  25000.00

I would like the results to return as:

**Amount     |State**

$100,000.00|AL

$145,000.00|AZ

Comment: (1) Sample data and desired results would help.  (2) A clear explanation of your logic as well.  (3) The SQL does not look like MySQL.  Tag the question with the database you are really using.

Comment: not related to c# or winforms

Comment: I've updated my quest, I can use C# and webforms if I need to change the way I'm doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q : I'm not sure the best way to do this?
A : no,it'll use multi slow query ,you can use `left join` subquery to avoid it,like below script :

```
SELECT        
    companyState, 
    CASE WHEN FondationOrder.pledgeStatus = 'canceled' THEN
        T.total
    ELSE 
        FondationOrder.pledgeAmount 
    END AS pledgeAmount
FROM FoundationCompanies
INNER JOIN FoundationContacts ON FoundationCompanies.companyId = FoundationContacts.companyId 
INNER JOIN FondationOrder ON FoundationContacts.contactId = FondationOrder.contactId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT orderId,SUM(paid) AS total
    FROM  FoundationInvoice
    GROUP BY orderId
) T on T.orderId = FondationOrder.orderId
GROUP BY FoundationCompanies.companyState
ORDER BY FoundationCompanies.companyState
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Order table to your join then use the aggregate function :

```
SELECT        
    dbo.FoundationCompanies.companyState,
    SUM(IIF(dbo.FondationOrder.pledgeStatus = 'canceled', dbo.FoundationInvoice.paid, dbo.FondationOrder.pledgeAmount)) AS pledgeAmount
FROM dbo.FoundationCompanies
INNER JOIN dbo.FoundationContacts ON dbo.FoundationCompanies.companyId = dbo.FoundationContacts.companyId
INNER JOIN dbo.FondationOrder ON dbo.FoundationContacts.contactId = dbo.FondationOrder.contactId
LEFT JOIN dbo.FoundationInvoice ON dbo.FondationOrder.orderId = dbo.FoundationInvoice.orderId
GROUP BY dbo.FoundationCompanies.companyState
```